# Synchronized in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, synchronization

I have an AsyncTask with a field named "sardine", in doInBackground() I call sardine.put(...) which makes network operations and run synchron. Now, while this is running, I need to be able to call sardine.abort() in a public method of the AsyncTask. I read that I should do a synchronized block on (this) but I am not sure of the consequences of this, now I am doing following:

```
public class AsyncWebDavUploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Integer> {

private SardinePatched sardine;    

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(final Void... params) {
    ...
    sardine = new Sardine...
    sardine.put(urlString, fileInputStream, mimeType, file.length(), true);
    ...    
    return result;

}

public void stopUplaod() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (sardine != null) {
                synchronized (sardine) {
                    sardine.abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

...
```

}

"sardine.put" does an "AbstractHttpClient.execute" and sardine.abort does an HttpRequestBase.abort, but I don't think this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use an AsyncTaskLoader and the LoaderManager. Then you can call Loader.cancelLoad.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

If you don't want to do than then using cancel(true) on the AsyncTask will interrupt it. You don't need any synchronized blocks or any new threads. Just handle the interrupted exception in the background method.

Comment: It may work, but I would like to know the solution using AsyncTask

Comment: You should be able to just call the cancel method of the async task, which should cause sardine to get an interrupted exception which you can handle. You don't need a background thread to do that. But it would be better if you provided more details on this "sardine" and "abort" method.

Comment: sardine is a Library used for make WebDav Request and abort aborts the connection. Calling cancel doesn't work because once in the doInBackground the Task is not canceled, cancel only avoids the Task to start or, if already started, that onPostExceute is not called

Comment: It seems that the abort method comes from the Apache Http Client

Comment: I think AsyncTask.cancel(true) is your best bet to interrupt it. "Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task."

Comment: cancel(true) is not interrupting the task, I think the HTTP Request locks the thread until it finishes

Comment: Locking isn't a thread feature but it could be blocked doing I/O, especially a socket connect. In that case, yes, you would have to close the socket, and probably only abort() can do that. Per this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/AbortableHttpRequest.html you don't need to call abort in a background thread.

Comment: I must call it in a background thread, otherwise I get an Exception from Android that it shouldn't run in the UI Thread